# Как искать информацию в нескольких таблицах?

Tags: php, mysql

Что нужно добавить в SQL-запрос, чтобы поиск информации был из 5 и более таблиц? Сейчас у меня ищет информацию только из таблицы `tableEpson`. Но есть ещё несколько: такие как `tableSamsung`, `tableKyocera` и т.д. Надо чтобы искало и по ним тоже. Что нужно добавить и как?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function search($words) {
    $words = strip_tags($words);
    if ($words === "") return false;
    $query_search = "";
    $arraywords = explode(" ", $words);
    foreach ($arraywords as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($arraywords[$key - 1])) 
            $query_search .= ' OR ';
        $query_search .= '`Model` LIKE "%'.$value.'%" OR `CartridgeNumber` LIKE "%'.$value.'%"';
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tableEpson, WHERE $query_search";
    $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "Имя пользователя", "Пороль", "Имя БД");
    $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);
    $mysqli->close();
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    return $results;
}

if (isset($_POST['bsearch'])) {
    $words = $_POST['words'];
    $results = search($words);
    print_r($results);
}
```

Comment: не баз данных а таблиц

Comment: ну да "Таблиц", спасибо за поправку. В спешке писал.

Comment: я думаю стоит вам над архитектурой бд подумать.

Comment: Если у вас добавится новый поставщик, например SONY , то судя по названиям таблиц вам придется создать для него новую таблицу tableSONY. А это нехорошо. Если вам сделать одну таблицу со всеми полями которые у вас есть в tableSamsung и добавить поле Provider - поставщик. Тогда и запросы можно будет легко писать, меняя в поле Where Provider = "samsung"

Comment: У меня все немного подругому с таблицой, можете посмотреть на скрин как выглядят мои таблицы и почему я сделал для каждой марки свою таблицу. СКРИН загрузил выше.

Comment: У меня просто для каждой марки очень много нужно прописывать модели и номера картриджей ну и цены за услуги. Поэтому я не придумал лучшего способа чем делать таблицу для каждой марки.

Comment: _можете посмотреть на скрин как выглядят мои таблицы и почему я сделал для каждой марки свою таблицу_ Скрин как раз демонстрирует, что сделано неправильно. Прислушайтесь к мнению **Alexus**. Если оставите как есть - дальше будет всё хуже и хуже, пока совсем не встанет колом.

Comment: А можете подсказать как лучше бы составить 1 таблицу в которой будет находиться такие бренды как Epson Samsung Panasonic Canon И  т.д. и в каждом бренде будет минимум по 40 моделей т.е. CANON LBP 800/810/1120,  
CANON LBP-1200/ 1210 и должен быть столбик Номер Картриджа в нем тоже список. И  так для каждого бренда. Т.е. мне надо сначала в html разметке сделать таблицу оформить ее, потом разделить ее на столбцы Model, CartridgeNumber и т.д. и список каждого бренда засунуть в Таблицу в БД вместе с тегами html??? Извините если непонятно для вас, не мог правильно изложить свои мысли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант по вашей картинке:

1. Модели принтеров таблица **models** с полями

   - ID  // 1
   - Name  // CANON FC-108
   - Series // 128/200/206...
2. Катриджы (**catridges**)

   - ID // 1
   - Name // FX-10
3. Катриджи Принтеров **printer_catridge** (на случай если принтер поддерживает несколько катриджей)

   - ModelID (ссылка на models.ID)
   - CatridgeID (ссылка на catridges.ID)
4. Цены на катриджи (**catridges_prices**)

   - CatridgeID (ссылка на catridge.ID)
   - price1
   - price2_3
   - ......
   - price11_13

Последнюю таблицу можно еще и дальше усовершенствовать.

Comment: Т.е. послучается надо сделать всего 4 отдельные друг от друга таблицы это : 1) Таблица models 2) Таблица cartridges и т.д

Comment: не подскажите как тут голосовать за ответ, чтобы вам в репутацию шло за помощь

Comment: @Дмитрий Как голосовать за ответ - наведите на треугольнички с цифрой 0 - будет подсказка, и жмите, что считаете нужным

Comment: и последний вопрос если позволите. Чтобы для каждого бренда например Canon, модели выводились в цикле в таблице как на скрине, что нужно сделать ? перечислить все модели Canon через запятую в таблице models колонке model_series? Или вместо запятых использовать теги td ?

Comment: @Дмитрий это уже вопрос дизайна, поэтому на ваше предпочтение

Answer (score 0):

Если все таблицы одинакового формата (с одинаковыми колонками), вам нужно сделать `UNION ALL` между `SELECT` запросами к каждой таблице, наподобие:

```
$myTables = array('tableEpson', 'tableSamsung');
$myQueries = array();
foreach ($myTables as $table) {
    $myQueries[] = "select * from $table where $query_search";
}
$query = implode(' union all ', $myQueries);`
```